# Hibernate FlushMode is set to Manual for multiple transactions

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

Here is my code :

```
HibernateUtil.pushFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
getCurrSess().beginTransaction();
try {
    for(i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        Obj dummy = list.get(i);
        // Here Multiple things can happen like selects, save, update and deletes of different objects which are related to dummy object....
        if (i > 0 && (i % 10 == 0)) {
            getCurrSess().getTran().commit();
            getCurrSess().beginTransaction();
            if (i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                getCurrSess().flush();
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
        }
    } 
} catch(Exception e) {
    getCurrSess().getTran().rollback();
} finally {
    HibernateUtil.popFlushMode();
}
```

Flush happens for every 10 committed transaction(i=100). This is part of a background job which takes up lots of processing. Number of objects vary around 20,000 and I cannot clear the session until the whole process is finished because I end up in Lazy initialization exception. My code works fine but here I'm bothered about the sequence of flush and commit in manual mode. Can this be done in a better way ?

Comment: Why not commit every time you do a flush?  There is no point in committing if you haven't done a flush.  Furthermore, even if you did that, your rollback won't work properly.  If you've already processed half your batch and you hit an error it's only going to roll back since the last commit which means the first half of your batch will still be committed to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on an application where we often got OptimisticLockExceptions during this kind of operation and to fix it we just reran the batch.  The downside is that you could still get a corrupted database if, for example, your database went offline halfway through the batch.

```
HibernateUtil.pushFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
try {
  int batchIndex = 0;
  int numAttempts = 0;
  while (batchIndex < list.size()) {
    listEnd = batchIndex+BATCH_SIZE;
    if(listEnd > list.size()) {
      listEnd = list.size();
    }
    ArrayList<> sublist = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(batchIndex, batchIndex+BATCH_SIZE));
    getCurrSess().beginTransaction();
    try {
      for(Object obj : list) {
        //Here multiple things can happen like selects, save, update, and deletes
      }
      getCurrSess().flush();
      getCurrSess().commit();
      batchIndex += BATCH_SIZE;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      getCurrSess().getTran().rollback();
      numAttempts++;
      if(numAttempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exceeded maximum number of attempts for batch operation, database is corrupted.");
      }
    }
  }
} finally {
  HibernateUtil.popFlushMode();
}
```

If you absolutely can't tolerate a corrupted database then you have to use a single transaction:

```
HibernateUtil.pushFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
try {
    getCurrSess().beginTransaction();
    try {
      for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Object obj = list.get(i);
        //Here multiple things can happen like selects, save, update, and deletes
        if(i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
          getCurrSess().flush();
        }
      }
      getCurrSess().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error occurred during batch.  Batch aborted.");
    }
  }
} finally {
  HibernateUtil.popFlushMode();
}
```

But obviously this is not going to give you great performance if you have 20,000 objects (in fact, even the first approach isn't going to be great).  If you do have 20,000 objects then the ONLY way you'll be able to improve performance is if you flush AND clear with each batch.  This means you will have to closely manage how you operate in order to avoid lazy initializer exceptions.

Comment: First approach looks great, and regarding the second approach  transaction is kept open for the whole period and may end up locking all tables/rows related to the operations/process until you commit. And may end up in dead locks. FYI: We use both Oracle and MySQL as back-end databases.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't get to have your cake and eat it too.  If you want automatic rollback management for the whole batch you have to have 1 transaction for the whole batch.  If you need short transactions then you'll have to implement a manual rollback/cleanup process for the transactions already committed or live with partially processed batches.

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason why you used constant `10` in modulo?

You should always want to do something for a reason :-) What I mean?

If you want to provide better throughput or you have small amount of RAM, I would provide cache flush&clear every cycle within iteration as small transactions bring this feature.

If you do not have this requirement depends on size of your list whether to commit at the end or during the iteration how you tried to design yourself. Be aware of constant `10` as sometimes it can be enough, sometime little, sometimes too much. I would prefer to decide when to flush according to other important sign, like count of objects in session or occupied memory etc. Note that you should not care only about size of hibernate cache but also about database transaction log.

If you take care about performance, look at stateless session, I've made [some performance](http://martin.podval.eu/2010/12/nhibernate-performance-isssues-insert.html) test before years (.NET)

Comment: The reason behind my module 10 is to keep the transaction duration short. Before this it was FlushMode.AUTO, when my above job is fired, all the users logged-in are seeing significant lag in every other use-case because of row locks in all tables, and due to this I came up with the above solution.

Comment: Well, I would do that every iteration in this cycle. Your obvious requirement is to keep transactions small so I would provide transaction per iteration. Note that once you provide small transactions breaking *business transaction* into small peaces you need to programatically handle transaction rollback of you business transaction - your job execution, probably using [transaction compensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensating_transaction). In other words you would be able to take all changes back in job execution granularity once any of you small transactions failed.

Comment: What happens if we commit before flush in Manual mode, will this work ?

Comment: I would say that all changes remain in cache, underlying transaction would be closed and it starts to perform queries w/o transaction. I believe it will fail with some exception regarding missing open transaction.

Comment: We are using Ehcache as our secondary level cache.

Comment: `Cache` in the sense of first level. Second level cache still requires opened transaction.